# How many subsisiaries can I have in NetSuite? I have Oneworld Netsuite Account

Tags: netsuite

I need to create 500 subsidiaries and these subsidiaries only stayed active for 1 year.

Is this possible in NetSuite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the help files:

Subsidiaries in OneWorld

Subsidiary licenses are sold on a per-country basis. You can have 125 subsidiaries in your NetSuite account, including the root subsidiary. Should you require more than 125 subsidiaries, contact your NetSuite account representative for pricing information.
License fees for subsidiaries do not include charges for elimination subsidiaries, and elimination subsidiaries do not count toward the maximum of 125 subsidiaries. Inactive subsidiaries also do not count toward the maximum.